# How to find the width of x-axis plotband widths dynamically in react-jsx-highstock (Highcharts)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, highcharts, react-hooks

I'm using https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-jsx-highstock library for plotting the data. I want to know the width of the plotbands dynamically, when I checked the Highcharts there are events **redraw** and **load** by which we can find the width of plotbands (http://jsfiddle.net/hfrntt/fdTEx/4661/). Now I want to know how this works in **react-jsx-highstock** library. As this library provides react components do not know where to add these events.

```
import { Chart, HighchartsStockChart, PlotBand, Series, useChart, XAxis, YAxis } from 'react-jsx-highstock'


<HighchartsStockChart plotOptions={plotOptions}>
    <Chart {...chartOptions} />
    <GenericOptions {...genericOptions} />

     <XAxis {...xAxis}>
       {(dayBands || []).map((plotBand) => (
         <PlotBand key={`{plotBand.label?.text}`} {...plotBand} />
       ))}
     </XAxis>

     <YAxis {...yAxis}>
       {(seriesData || []).map((series, index) => (
          <Series key={index} id={index} {...series} />
        ))}
      </YAxis>
</HighchartsStockChart>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I encourage you to use the highcharts-react-official wrapper which is fully supported.

https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-react

https://www.npmjs.com/package/highcharts-react-official

And later, please reproduce your issue on the online editor with the sample data, you can start from this demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/highcharts-react-demo-gnev1?file=/demo.jsx